# Using VB, VS 2013 How to use a DLL outside of the working directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am using writing in Visual Basic using  Visual Studio 2013 and trying to use the debuger for code in a DLL that is outside of the working directory. The dll is  a c++ project and the main app is a VB project.

How do I do that? In c++ it seems to be straight forward but not with VB.

Below is purely for background. I am interested in the question above in general and this is just the latest manifestation.
The full story: I am trying to debug the VB program and a DLL written in C++. I copied the the DLL into the working directory of the VB exe directory. But it gives me a tool tip at the break point in the DLL source code that reads "breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols loaded for this document." I am trying to figure out if that fixes the problem. If it does, it does. If it doesn't, it doesn't.

Comment: Only the last paragraph seems to make sense.  Any breakpoints you set cannot be armed until the native C++ DLL is loaded by your VB program.  Whatever statement that does that must execute, usually a call to a method declared as [DllImport] or with the Declare statement.  You must also enable the unmanaged debugger.  The debugger's Debug > Windows > Modules window shows what is loaded, if it is not in the list then a breakpoint can't work.

Comment: @Hans, You are 100% right. Only the last paragraph made sense. I edited the first paragraph. I did not make it clear that I was trying to get the debugger going into the dll.(Which was the most point!) Hopefully this helps. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pehaps you should p-invoke ([enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx)) to make a call and import that .dll. The other option would be to register dll in gac and make wrapper com for your library.

You should also add the library to your .NET application as follows:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)DLL\$(ConfigurationName)"\*.dll "$(TargetDir)"*.* /Y
```

Project-->Properties-->Compile-->Build Events-->Post-build event command line pass the command.